# How can I read a file in nodejs without fs?

Tags: node.js, webpack, fs

Everyone tells to use `fs` when it comes to reading a file, but I'm unable to use `fs` with `webpack` because of an open [issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/447). Apparently there are no alternatives.

How can I read text from file on local disk without `fs`?

Comment: did you tried https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/447#issuecomment-285598881 ?

Comment: I did, when I insert "node: {fs: 'empty'}" I simply get "TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function" when I try to use it. I tried a couple of things to fix but nothing... it seems that it is much simplier if it were an alternative

Comment: You tried using raw-loader?

Comment: Yes, raw-loader allows me to read source code from other files, great. If you answer I will accept it.